# My menuitems in list view are not displaying Xamarin

Tags: xaml, xamarin

I've just started learning Xamarin,  I have a problem while creating a listview. I want to create a button below each item in the list so I've seen that Xamarin gives you an option to create a button, MenuItem, but when I display my view it is not showed anywhere. This is the code of the listView, I believe that rest of the code is not necessary but if it is, I will edit.

```
                    <ListView x:Name="lvActivities" HasUnevenRows="True"
                    RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
                Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=0,Constant=0}"
                    RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
                Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=0.2,Constant=0}"
                    RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
                Type=RelativeToView, Property=Width, Factor=1, Constant=0,ElementName=rlAlumnInfo}"
                    RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
                Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=0.76, Constant=0}">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate >
                        <DataTemplate >
                            <ViewCell >
                                <Grid >
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>

                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                    <Label Text="{Binding title}" FontSize="20" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5,5,5,5" />


                                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5,5,5,5">
                                        <Label Text="Aula :" FontSize="20"/>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding cRoom}" FontSize="20" Margin="8,0,0,0"/>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5,5,5,5" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                                        <Label Text="Dia :" FontSize="20"/>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding dateHour}" FontSize="20" Margin="8,0,0,0"/>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </Grid>

                                <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                                    <MenuItem Text="Eliminar"  Clicked="deleteActivity_Clicked" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                                </ViewCell.ContextActions>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
```

Comment: Hi , which platform device (iOS/Android) you tested in ? And have you checked this [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/userinterface-listview-interactivity/) whether it works . You also can show your sample link here , I will check it .

Comment: I have checked shared code in local site , there is no problem . I think you can check whether the version of Xamarin.Forms is the latest .

Comment: ContextActions are visible via a left swipe on iOS or a long press on Android